# SwingWorker to run class that creates threads. Java

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swingworker

I have "Creator" class that has anonymous inner runnable class that creates threads. I also have GUI class that creates GUI and on button press executes the "Creator" class. But then my GUI freezes until all threads created by "Creator" are completed. I found that SwingWorker could help me in this situation, but I fail to understand how to create one in this particular situation. And is there any other easy way to do that, than SwingWorker?

Here is the code for my Creator class:

```
public class Creator {

    final ExecutorService es;
    Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<>();


    public Creator() {
        es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    }

    public void runCreator() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            futures.add(es.submit(new Check(i)));
        }

        es.shutdown();

        for (Future<?> future : futures) {
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }

    }

    private class Check implements Runnable {

    private int i;

        private Check(int i) {
            this.i = i;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

    System.out.println("Number: "+i);

    try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show some of your code where you are creating the threads?

Comment: Ok I'll edit my code, i'll try to make it as simple as I can

Comment: thank you, it looks like this is happening because of your calls to Future's get method.

Comment: Yea, now I got it myself too, but I cant remove it since I need to know when threads have completed

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is hanging until it completes, is because of the call to your [Future's get method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29). This will wait until it has completed. Also, you probably do not want to shutdown your pool right after adding all of your threads. It would be better to just add a on close event and shut it down there.

Since all that you are doing is printing a number and sleeping, you do not need to wait for the Future to complete. Just remove the call to get and the delay should stop.

Comment: what is your inner runnable class for?

Comment: that wouldnt effect a runable in a thread pool though. You would expect it to return control once it has been submitted to the pool. Unless maybe the poster is calling get() on the returned Future?

Comment: But I also need to know when threads have completed, how I manage that?

Comment: But that is simplified code, actually it does much more things that is shown in code, and I just must know when threads have completed

Comment: It might be worth having your runnables be able to signal when they are completed. what do they need to do?

Comment: they scan for open ports. but how can i make it signal when its completed? because only way i know to find out if threads are completed is future.get(); method.

Comment: what do they do if they find an open port?

Comment: add it to array list of open ports, nothing else

Comment: make it so your threads can access your collection, then just have them add it directly.

Comment: if the only thing that your threads are doing are independent tasks and just add them to an array I am not sure why you would need to know?

Comment: Because I need to know whether scanning is in progress or not.

Comment: Wouldn't scanning always be in progresses, in case a port opened up or became in use? Besides that though, can you describe in a little more detail what you are trying to do? There may be alternative ways to look into but I cannot really suggest any without knowing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Swing worker is the way to go - there are enough examples on the web, but to summarize - put your thread-spawning and waiting code in `doInBackground()`, if you want to report interim progress, use `publish()/process()` and finally, get your data to the Swing EDT thread in `done()`.

PS. irrelevant to the SwingWorker usage, you might want to consider using a completion service rather than waiting on all futures in order.